# Updating null field with the value in the same column A based on the value of another column B where the value of B is the same

Tags: ms-access

| title | genre | band |
| --- | --- | --- |
| wish you were here | rock | Pink Floyd |
| Have a cigar |  | Pink Floyd |
| Time |  | Pink Floyd |

How do I update the genre column based on the band column so that it looks like this:

| title | genre | band |
| --- | --- | --- |
| wish you were here | rock | Pink Floyd |
| Have a cigar | rock | Pink Floyd |
| Time | rock | Pink Floyd |

This is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE [music] INNER JOIN [music] AS [music_1] ON [music].[band] = [music_1].[band] SET [music].[genre] = [music_1].[genre]
WHERE ((([music].[genre]) Is Null));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `DLookup`:

```sql
Update 
    Music
Set 
    genre = Nz(DLookup("genre", "Music", "band = '" & music.band & "' And genre Is Not Null"), "<Unknown>")
Where 
    genre Is Null
```

It may be slow ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I tried this solution and Access returned the error "operation must use an updateable query" :/

Comment: You are probably right. Try with `DLookup` as shown.

Comment: It's okay if it's slow, the database isn't that big :) unfortunately, it didn't work. This time around the error was "a type conversion failure." I will say that the number of fields to update is correct. I checked the types of the fields and they're all of type short text. so, I'm unsure why it's giving back this error.

Comment: Perhaps some bands have no genre at all ... ? See extended answer, please.

Comment: Your solution worked so thank you so much for the taking the time to help!